Mass Delete picklist value (Not Manually)
We have multiple question on this topic but I didn't get any answer to mass delete the Picklist values at once.
Most of them are old and I do not want to go for manual approach as there are almost 20000 inactive values. Also, these are in Production, and I do not want to take any chance to click on "Delete unused value" button as my field is an unbound Picklist, on using this button it might become 'Bounded'.
Can anyone please guide me here.

Will this work for you Bulk Delete Inactive Picklist Values? It has various restrictions.

I had gone through this SF doc, actually it says:
"After you delete unused values, if a picklist is unbound and the total number of inactive values falls below the limit, the field is set to a bound picklist." And my picklist is unbounded.

Does this answer your question? Mass Delete Picklist values

This is an old post, Now we do have option in Sf to select all the picklist value at once available in single page. But there are only 30 picklist value in one page, which will not help me in delting 20k record.

This is not a delete, but AFAIK the API supports that too. Does mean writing some Apex code though. https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/how-to-update-the-values-of-a-custom-picklist-field-using-metadata-api/.

I will try this code once with delete.
